# Pyspark dataframe iteration based on Column datatype

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe with columns struct, Integers and other columns. I want to select only struct column dynamically (without knowing column names, maybe multiple columns present). Please someone help me this in PySpark

Comment: can you show an example please?

Comment: if your dataframe is called `df`, then `df.dtypes` is a list of tuples of the form (column name, column type), so you can iterate over that

Comment: Thanks ags29, this is really helpful. Now I am getting the column names and datatypes as a List and I use string comparision with the datatype and getting the required columns in new list, then using Spark SQL select statement (dataframe select can also be used) to get columns of required datatypes. I hope this is the efficient approach. Any other ways of doing this?

Comment: sounds good to me, in terms of other ways to approach it, see answer below (which is fairly similar to what I was proposing)

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve `struct` columns using list comprehension, and then plug the result in a `select()` statement:

```
cols = [i.name for i in df.schema.fields if "StructType" in str(i.dataType)]
df.select(cols)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Got what I am looking for